# Using LDAP Authentication only for sysops only but allow read-only access to anonymous

Tags: mediawiki, ldap-client

I have LDAP Authentication installed and it is running great. My only problem is, that if you're not a logged in user, you can't see any of the content. You get an error that says:

Content Encoding Error: The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because it uses an invalid or unsupported form of compression.

But when I log back in I can access all my pages. Why am I getting that error when I'm not logged in, and how can I enable read only mode for people who don't have accounts?

I have this configured in my localsettings.php

```
$wgGroupPermissions['*']['view'] = true;
```

Wiki Version: 1.21.1 LDAP Authentication Version: 2.0d

Answer (score 0):

'''Solution'''
I had this:
`$wgUseGzip = false;`

Set to true.
Once I set it to false, everything worked again.